# There is no Sample ( demo ) data for Moodle?

Tags: php, xml, moodle, demo

I usually use wordpress, and i can at any time, download a demo data, to test a full functional website wordpress with demo data ( i import xml file with wordpress importer) .
But in moodle, i searched for a demo data, to test a moodle website, but i can't find it ... 
So where can i download a demo file, or a database to test and view how moodle works in my own localhost.

example of demo data wordpress :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel>
<item>
        <title></title>
        <link>http://themetrust.com/demos/work/?p=125</link>
        <pubDate>Mon, 20 Dec 2010 16:09:14 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Henry]]></dc:creator>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://themetrust.com/demos/work/?p=125</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[ ]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>125</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2010-12-20 16:09:14</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2010-12-20 16:09:14</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>125</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>4</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>nav_menu_item</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
                                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_classes</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_target</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_object</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[page]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_object_id</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[113]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_menu_item_parent</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[0]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_type</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[post_type]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_xfn</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_menu_item_url</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
                            </item>
</channel>
```

Thank you !

Comment: @rnevius Why minus 2 ?

Comment: I also wondered about the down-votes. Perhaps the question could be worded better, but the intent is clear and it's a good thing to ask.

Comment: @SamWilson Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can use the generator tool from the command line to create users, enrolments and courses

```
php admin/tool/generator/cli/maketestsite.php --size=S
```

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Test_site_generator

Also have a look at Moosh for creating activities etc from the command line.

http://moosh-online.com/commands/